# Setup two ISPs and apple routers to fail over through Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, router, internet

I want to setup a network with two internet connections where it can failover in case one of the ISPs is not working. I am not sure if this is possible with the infrastructure and physical constrains I have.

- ISP 1 is a Cable Internet Service
- ISP 2 is a ASDL service
- ISP 1 has the NAT turned off and is connected to the "Apple Airport Express".
- "Apple Airport Express" creates de the network (makes DHCP and NAT) and provides internet.
- "Apple Airport Extreme" is extending the network created by the "Apple Airport Express" and has connected its WAN port the ISP2

What I want to achieve is that the Wifi network is created by the Apple Routers and if they can manage a fail over of the internet connection over Wifi.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible with what you have. You would have to have two separate WiFi networks between both airports and you would have to manually switch from one WiFi network to the other. What you need is a dual-WAN capable router that both ISPs connect in to before any airport is hooked up. One device has to decide when to failover and how to route packets.

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you for your answer, I have a Netgear N600 I will check if I can have a dual wan router with that

Comment: No, the N600 won't do it either. Having failover or dualhomed connections is very much an enterprise feature and you'll pay for it. There's various ways of setting it up yourself but they are far too deep to go into on a SU answer.

Comment: @djsmiley2k thank you for the answer. I think now my biggest problem is that I can not put both ISPs together so I am able to connect them to the same router.

Comment: Yes. Do research into routers which will carry dual connections from ISP's. You'll spend (a lot) more money however to achieve this, or you can do the research yourself and setup something like pfsense, or a linux box, to do it for you (Amusingly a raspi could do it infact).

Comment: @djsmiley2k thank you for the answer again. Besides I will save money, researching is more fun. Thank you for the data

Comment: Here here to pfsense. Don't waste your money on a dual wan Soho router. They are usually junk, and over priced, usually will only do basic fail-over with no load-balancing. Go with pfsense, it's easy to get going what your trying to accomplish.